# Voltage across resistor

Tags: c#

```
private void seriesres_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i=0;
    double finalanswer=0;

     string phrase = Conversion_Value.Text;  // input to string
     double[] doubles = phrase.Split(',').Select(Double.Parse).ToArray();

     for (i = 0; i < doubles.Length; i++)
     {
         finalanswer = finalanswer + doubles[i];
     }
     Answer.Text = finalanswer.ToString("F6"); // STRING TO DOUBLE WITH 6 DECIMAL PLACES
     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     double voltage = double.Parse(INPUT_VOLTAGE.Text); // CONVERT FROM STRING TO DOUBLE
     double current = voltage / finalanswer;
     for (i = 0; i < doubles.Length; i++)
     {
         double resistorvoltage = doubles[i] * current;
         VOLTAGE_LIST.Text = resistorvoltage.ToString("F6"); // STRING TO DOUBLE WITH 6 DECIMAL PLACES
     }
}
```

I am trying to make an aditional code that outputs the voltage across each resistor in the list in the bottom left textbox in the program when the "Series" button is pressed.  the code in question is the section under the ////////////////////////.
the text box in visual studio is named "VOLTAGE_LIST".

[image: link to the immage of my program]

Comment: Change `VOLTAGE_LIST.Text = resistorvoltage.ToString("F6");` to `VOLTAGE_LIST.Text += resistorvoltage.ToString("F6") + "\r\n";`

Comment: VOLTAGE_LIST.Text += "VR("i")= " + resistorvoltage.ToString("F6") + "\r\n";

Comment: is there any way to add VR(i)=  to the front of each output?  i being the resistor number?  when i run the code commented above it says ; is expected

Comment: got it, have to add + before and after the i.  THANK YOU!!